# input of type number not preventing inputs beyond the max

Tags: html, reactjs

```html
<input
  className="input cost-input"
  type="number"
  id="cost"
  name="cost"
  min={0}
  max={1000000}
  placeholder="$"
/>
```

Even though a `min` and a `max` are provided, I am still able to enter negative values as well as values beyond `1000000`.

Comment: Attribute values should be within quotes, not braces. Ie `min="0" max="1000000"`. Also, HTML5 form validation only kicks in on submit. See [Constraint validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Constraint_validation)

Comment: It does not prevent you from manually entering in a value greater than the max or less than the min. The validation would fail when the form submits.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a question, it is a restatement of fact.